# location save by click

Tags: javascript, php

what im trying to accomplish is to add a marker on a location in which i clicked and if i clicked on a location that isnt marked that it will be marked, in addition i would like to add a mark from a text box which gets input from the user on the map , the map will open automatically on the location from the text box and all the other mark places will be save in a data base , after wards when i open the map i want the previous location to marked automatically from the database.

eg:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

thank you in advance,
Chen.

Comment: Can you post code please.

Answer (score 0):

To handle your map click events you use:

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, "click", yourHandler);
```

where `gmap` is a reference to you map instance
and `yourHandler` is a click handler.

you can then add a marker to your map, in your click handler like this:

```
function yourHandler (event) {

  console.log("LatLng", `${event.latLng.lat()}, ${event.latLng.lng()}`);

  var latLng = { 
      lat: event.latLng.lat(), 
      lng: event.latLng.lng()
  }

  const markerData = {
            position: latLng,
            map: gmap,
            title: "new marker",
            draggable: false            
        };

    const gmarker = new window.google.maps.Marker(markerData);
}
```

where `gmap` is a reference to your map instance.

From this your should be able to derive the rest, to complete your question, but feel free to add questions.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code i don't understand how i can add this code in my code ?

```
<p><button class="w3-btn w3-blue" onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button></p>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
        }
        else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
        lat=position.coords.latitude;
        lon=position.coords.longitude;
        latlon=new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
        mapholder=document.getElementById('mapholder')
        mapholder.style.height='100%';
        mapholder.style.width='100%';

        var myOptions={
            center:latlon,zoom:17,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl:false,
            navigationControlOptions:{style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL}
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapholder"),myOptions);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:latlon,map:map,title:"You are here!"});
    }

    function showError(error)
    {
        switch(error.code)
        {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
                break;
            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
                break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
                x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
                break;
            case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
                break;
        }
    }
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, "click", yourHandler);
window.google.maps.event.add
</script>
```